# Android Intent with Gallery application to display images with a File ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-intent

I implemened a file ContentProvider to access a file server on a wifi network through http urls.

What I am trying to do is to launch the Android Gallery app with a particular intent and uri to display image files that are in a particular directory on my file server.

I am able to succeed if I launch the Gallery app with a single uri to display one image through this code :

```
Intent lance = new Intent();
lance.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String typedata = "image/*";
lance.setType(typedata);
String phuri = "content://" + URI_AUTORITE
                     + "/" + URI_CONTENU_FICHIERS
                     + directory + filename;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(phuri);
lance.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
startActivity(lance);
```

But I am trying to go one step further to implement the display of a directory containing images. I tried to use the ClipData object to display several images, through this code :

```
Intent lance = new Intent();
lance.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String typedata = "image/*";
lance.setType(typedata);
String phuri = "content://" + URI_AUTORITE
                     + "/" + URI_CONTENU_FICHIERS
                     + directory + filename;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(phuri);
ClipData ensemble = ClipData.newRawUri("Photos", uri);
lance.setClipData(ensemble);
startActivity(lance);
```

It doesn't work : the Gallery app is launched and display the list of albums and doesn't call my File ContentProvider.

Dis I miss something or is it a problem for the Gallery app developpers ?

Answer (score 0):

You should override getType() method of your content provider to return mime type of image like so

```
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return "image/*";
}
```

Comment: My getType method returns the right string, but it isn't enough. The galery app doesn't try to read the content of the clipdata ...

Comment: Did you set exported=true in manifest file for your content provider?